# Scala methods with no argument evaluating on definition in zeppelin

Tags: scala, apache-spark, methods, apache-zeppelin, evaluation

I'm writing a method in zeppelin that will update several DataFrames, to be called as part of initializing my code.

The pattern we're following is to define all initialization methods in their own paragraphs, and then call them as part of a block.

```
def init(nc: NotebookContext) = {
    method1()
    method2()
}
```

However, for most definition signatures of methods without parameters, it appears that zeppelin is actually calling and evaluating the last method in a paragraph. This is a problem, because when the method is called later, it means the transformations have been applied to the DataFrame twice, which is not desired.

Is this a function of scala, or a quirk of zeppelin, or both?  Why do some of these declarations evaluate immediately, while others wait to be called?

Assume the below methods are each defined in their own zeppelin paragraph

```
def runsAutomatically(): Unit = { println("test") }
//runsAutomatically: ()Unit
//test
def runsAutomatically2 = { println("test2") }
//runsAutomatically2: Unit
//test2
def waitsForDefinition= () => { println("test") }
//waitsForDefinition: () => Unit
```

I understand that there is a difference in scala between functions/methods with no parameter lists, and a single parameter list with no parameters, but I don't know why these different version would change when things get executed.

Finally if done in a single paragraph:

```
def runsAutomatically(): Unit = { println("test") }
def runsAutomatically2 = { println("test") }
//runsAutomatically: ()Unit
//runsAutomatically2: Unit
//test2
```

Is this just a quirk of zeppelins, or something about Scala I'm missing?

Comment: Really think this has to do with Zeppelin, in that even things explicitly defined as lazy like
var x = 5
lazy val waitMore = { println("test5" + x)}
immediately evaluates if it is the last thing in a paragraph, but adding a println after there definition and then redefining x in a second paragraph before calling waitMore has the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because in scala, a `def` without an empty parameter list is a strict value; In the end it's actually just a val.

Scala is a strict language and not making the function a thunk by not adding an empty parameter list will actually be evaluated immediately.

Comment: Learning a bit more about call by name in relation to this question was interesting, but I don't know that this is actually the case here. In ["on method invocations"](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/on-method-invocations-or-what-exactly-is-eta-expansion-1019b37e010c/), Sinisa Louc says that a def f = "foo" is basically a value "whose evaluation is performed every time it is accessed". The key here is that I'm not trying access the value at the time of declaration, but if it is the last item in a paragraph, zeppelin appears to access it to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, none of these methods should get evaluated automatically. At least, not in pure Scala.

```
def runsAutomatically(): Unit = { println("test") }
def runsAutomatically2 = { println("test2") }
def waitsForDefinition= () => { println("test") }
```

You should blame Zeppelin for that then. What version of Zeppelin are you using? I don't see this problem in Zeppelin `0.9.0` - maybe an upgrade would be the option for you?

Comment: I'm using 0.8.0, and I think I agree that this is about Zeppelin not specifically Scala.  I think that Zeppelin wants each paragraph to have a "result" so it is evaluating whatever the last value in a paragraph is.